# To start a desktop java application with bluetooth do I need JavaME?

Tags: java, bluetooth

To start a **desktop** java application with bluetooth I need JavaME?

My notebook have a bluetooth usb dongle, and I'll develop an application using it. Do I need to use JavaME? Will it work on desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bluetooth is a JSR-82 (API for Bluetooth) specification. You can download JRS-82 implemented Bluetooth library like [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/). Alternatively, you can view this [page](http://javabluetooth.com/development_kits.html) for lists for Bluetooth development kit.

Comment: The page you linked is no more useful.